# Laravel mailhog でメール送信テスト エラー Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client():

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail

docker で動かしているLaravel でメール送信テストをするため mailhog を導入しました。
しかし、エラーが発生して送信することができません。

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mailhog failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

動作環境：
php 8.1.8
Laravel Framework 8.83.23
sail 8.1

maihogの導入のため、次の手順で処理を行いました
１）docker-compose.yml

```
mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
        - "1025:1025"
        - "8025:8025"
```

２）.env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="admin@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

//追加
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

３）docker-imageの更新
`docker-compose build --no-cache`

４）sailの起動
`sail up -d`

５）mailhogの受信箱確認
`http://localhost:8025` 正常に表示

６）メール送信＝＞エラー
７）エラーが発生するために設定を変更してみました
.envの `MAIL_HOST` を `mail` `localhost` にしても同様のエラー

完全に手詰まってしまっています。
後はどこをチェックすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
        - "1025:1025"
        - "8025:8025"
    networks:
        - sail
```

上記の通り、最後にnetworksを追加することで解決しました。
追加後、 `docker-compose build --no-cache` でビルド

Answer (score 0):

同じ現象にハマったのですが、私の場合は設定ファイル自体はあっていました。
ものすごく分かりにくいのですが、下の画像のConnectedのところ、
この状態だと接続拒否になっているので、クリックしてDisConnectedにしたら動きました。

どうみても今現在がConnectedで繋がっているという意味にしか見えませんが、これを押すとConnectedにするよって意味なのかもしれません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]